# My BTC was stolen using my Blockchain pairing code

Tags: blockchain.info, fraud, theft

I was having a issue with my blockchain account, so I searched for help on Facebook. Then I got a message from some obviously not related to Blockchain (I didn't know this at the time) but acted as their support team and wanting to help resolve my issue. This person requested my blockchain pairing code so he could fix the problem. After providing it to him, all my BTC was sent out of my account. How did he access my account with just my pairing code?

Comment: If a spam/shill answer is posted it will be deleted, but as it stands currently, the only answer does contain beneficial and correct information which addresses the question. So I won't delete the question.

Answer (score 20):

Blockchain.info pairing code allows you to sync wallets. For example, it's for when you have coins on your phone and you want to be able to spend them from your computer. So, they synced their wallet with your account, including the private keys, and stole your coins.

[From their website](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/207449986-General):

> As with your wallet ID, you should never share your pairing code with anyone. The pairing code grants full access to your wallet and its funds. It should be used only by you, when you want to access your wallet on your mobile device.